# Why is Sass striping semicolons?

Tags: sass, compass

I'm using Compass to compile a Sass Zen theme. I got this warning:

```
 Compass has changed how browser support is configured. The following configuration         variables are no longer supported: $legacy-support-for-ie6, $legacy-support-for-ie7, $legacy-support-for-ie8
```

I installed older versions of

```
compass (0.12.7)
sass (3.2.19)
breakpoint (1.3)
```

I'm no longer getting the warning, however, I'm losing semicolons in the compiled code. Example:

```
/* Address paddings set differently in IE 6/7. */
menu,
ol,
ul {
padding: 0 0 0 $indent-amount; /* LTR */
}

@if $legacy-support-for-ie7 {
/* Correct list images handled incorrectly in IE 7. */
nav ul,
nav ol {
list-style: none;
list-style-image: none;
}
```

Compiles to

```
menu,
ol,
ul {
padding: 0 0 0 30px 
/* LTR */
}
```

Notice the missing semicolon. It seems like everywhere there's an `@if $legacy-support-for-ie` compass then strips the preceding semicolon. 
There are 51 declarations of @if $legacy-support-for-ie in my files, I'd rather just leave them if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had issues with using the latest version of compass when a site was setup to use the pre 1.0 release of compass. Try using Compass 0.12.7 and then rebuilding your dependencies from there. https://rubygems.org/gems/compass/versions/0.12.7

Comment: What does this have to do with semicolons being stripped?

Comment: Yep, I built a new gemset with compass 0.12.7 and it filled in all the dependancies. thanks!

Comment: @cimmanon It's not so much an explanation but a way to get around the things compass does when you update your gem. I've had issues with the new version of compass with a project that started on the old one, and if you revert to the old one it solves wacky issues like this. I think you're other answer is a good one to understand the fundamentals of the answer.

Comment: There is no indication that Sass changed how the trailing semicolon is handled between 3.2 (compatible with Compass 0.12) and 3.3 (compatible with Compass 1.0).  The trailing semicolon appears in all output types other than compressed.  I certainly couldn't reproduce the OP's claims using sassmeister.

Answer (score 1):

The `$legacy-support-for-ie` has nothing to do with the very last semicolon being dropped.  That's a particular of Compass.

Sass does not care how your code is formatted as long as it is valid.  When the CSS is generated, it follows the style rules dictated by the chosen output style for things like whitespace, indentation, punctuation, etc.  You can only specify a different output style, not change the particulars of any given style.

Note that omitting the final semicolon is completely valid according to CSS.